# Edit neovim start screen without plugins

Tags: neovim

i like to edit this neovim start screen

```
                 NVIM v0.6.1                                                                                          

Nvim is open source and freely distributable
           https://neovim.io/#chat

type  :help nvim<Enter>       if you are new!
type  :checkhealth<Enter>     to optimize Nvim
type  :q<Enter>               to exit
type  :help<Enter>            for help

        Help poor children in Uganda!
type  :help iccf<Enter>       for information
```

But, without any plugin, i tried searching a file on `/usr/share/nvim/runtime` but i not found anything

How i can change that start screen?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted so I ended up writing a very small plugin. It's a one file with ~100 lines of code so you can literally copy it and put it in your `init.lua` if you wanted
https://github.com/eoh-bse/minintro.nvim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The intro screen is hardcoded in Vim/Neovim source and is not customizable.
2. Instead, it is possible to write some stuff into text buffer and erase it after a while. This will require some bits of scripting though. This is how "plugins" work.
3. "Plugin" is a collection of script lines needed to implement extra functionality. So "plugin" is not too much different from "~/.vimrc" or "/usr/share/nvim/runtime" etc., except it was written by another person. If you don't like other people's code then go and do it better.

Comment: Thanks for saying that, it's not that I don't like other people's code but it would be nice to edit this screen without using plugins but thanks for the reply ^^